# OSGi Felix: secure REST resources through annotations

Tags: rest, authorization, osgi, amdatu

I'm developing an **OSGi-based** Web application that exposes several **REST** resources. To do so, I exploited two packages of [Amdatu project](http://www.amdatu.org/), namely `org.amdatu.web.rest.jaxrs` and `org.amdatu.web.rest.wink`.

The system works well, but now I have to solve some security issues. After login, my OSGi server provides the user with a JWT token, in which user's role is stored. This token is sent back to the server for each request in the Authorization header.

I'm able to trivially check both the validity of the token and the user's role at the beginning of the resource method, but I'd like to do so through annotations. By extending the `javax.servlet.Filter interface`, I implemented a filter class that is able to intercept all the http requests.

Unfortunately, from within this class I cannot know which annotations are set for the resource method (the HttpServletRequest object gives only the resource path information).

So, my question is: is there a way to check the resource method annotations from within the filter class in order to properly process the JWT?

I found several solutions based on Jersey, but it conflicts with the aforementioned Amdatu packages..
Thanks in advance.